# Multiple Spring Configuration files (one per Profile)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I'm a Spring rookie and trying to benefit from the advantages of the easy 'profile' handling of Spring. I already worked through this tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile and now I'd like to adapt that concept to an easy example.
I've got two profiles: `dev` and `prod`. I imagine a `@Configuration` class for each profile where I can instantiate different beans (implementing a common interface respectively) depending on the set profile.

My currently used classes look like this:

*StatusController.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/status")
public class StatusController {

    private final EnvironmentAwareBean environmentBean;

    @Autowired
    public StatusController(EnvironmentAwareBean environmentBean) {
        this.environmentBean = environmentBean;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Status getStatus() {
        Status status = new Status();
        status.setExtra("environmentBean=" + environmentBean.getString());
        return status;
    }
}
```

*EnvironmentAwareBean.java*

```
public interface EnvironmentAwareBean {
    String getString();
}
```

*EnvironmentAwareBean.java*

```
@Service
public class DevBean implements EnvironmentAwareBean {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "development";
    }
}
```

*EnvironmentAwareBean.java*

```
@Service
public class ProdBean implements EnvironmentAwareBean {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "production";
    }
}
```

*DevConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevConfig {

    @Bean
    public EnvironmentAwareBean getDevBean() {
        return new DevBean();
    }
}
```

*ProdConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdConfig {

    @Bean
    public EnvironmentAwareBean getProdBean() {
        return new ProdBean();
    }

}
```

Running the example throws this exception during startup (`SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT` is set to `dev`):

(...) UnsatisfiedDependencyException: (...) nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [EnvironmentAwareBean] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: prodBean,devBean,getDevBean

Is my approach far from a recommended configuration? In my opinion it would make more sense to annotate each `Configuration` with the `@Profile` annotation instead of doing it for each and every bean and possibly forgetting some variants when new classes are added later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementations of `EnvironmentAwareBean` are all annotated with `@Service`.

This means they will all be picked up by component scanning and hence you get more than one matching bean. Do they need to be annotated with `@Service`?

Annotating each `@Configuration` with the `@Profile` annotation is fine. Another way as an educational exercise would be to not use `@Profile` and instead annotate the `@Bean` or Config classes with your own implementation of `@Conditional`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just removed the `@Service` annotation and now it works as I think it should :)
I'll look into the `@Conditional` annotation too.